# Alternating Bitwise concatenation in C

Tags: c, integer, bit-manipulation, concatenation

I want to concatenate two integers a, b in C like this:

If a has the bitwise representation `a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4...` and b has the bitwise representation `b_1 b_2 b_3 b_4...` I want my result to be `a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 a_3 b_3 a_4 b_4`.

For example: a = 5 = `0101`, b = 9 = `1001`

Then my result should be `01100011`. Is there a (simple) way to do it in C?

EDIT: Solved it with the "Interleave bits the obvious way" from the Bit Twiddling Hacks from the comments. I merged two uint32_t to one uint64_t. The use of it was to merge two streams but with the constraint that if two different pairs of values are close to each other, the merged ones should also have a small difference.

Comment: There's a **straight forward** way: determine every single bit (`&` with a shifted 1bit mask) and shift into your result. That's not "simple" though. What's the purpose of this exercise? Maybe there's a better way to solve the problem that lead to this idea?

Comment: Personally I'd write a "padding function" which yields `a_1 0 a_2 0 a_3 0 a_4` etc. Call that on your two numbers, further offset one of them and `|` them to get the result.

Comment: What do you intend to do with overflow?  Until you define that, no solution is possible.

Comment: Search for "interleave bits" on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) ...

Comment: Right now, this isn't a good question: 1.) An answer would require to write code that isn't there yet (we're more about helping with existing code in general, although this isn't a *strict* requirement) 2.) The problem isn't completely defined, as pointed out by Martin 3.) The purpose is unclear -- it might appear to make a lot more sense if you also explain *why* you want to do this.

Comment: If this turns out to be performance critical and you're on a reasonably modern x86 cpu, you can use `pdep` to do this in two or three instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Among the methods suggested by [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious), I think using lookup tables could be a reasonable way. It is simple and scalable to any input size.

Consider interleaving two 2-bit values `a` and `b`. The result is a 4-bit value `c`. For each value of `a`, we can calculate the shifted value of `a` in `c` and build a table.

```
// a = 00  =>  c = 0x0x : x denotes the position where the bits of b goes
// a = 01  =>  c = 0x1x
// a = 10  =>  c = 1x0x
// a = 11  =>  c = 1x1x

a_table[4] = { 0, 2, 8, 10 }; // in binary format : { 0000, 0010, 1000, 1010 }
```

Similarly for b:

```
// b = 00  =>  c = x0x0
// b = 01  =>  c = x0x1
// b = 10  =>  c = x1x0
// b = 11  =>  c = x1x1

b_table[4] = { 0, 1, 4, 5 }; // in binary format : { 0000, 0001, 0100, 0101 }
```

Now interleaving `a` and `b` is as simple as:

```
c = a_table[a] | b_table[b]
```

Instead of interleaving two 2-bit values, you can consider interleaving larget number of bits at a time. The loookup table shown at [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableLookup) is the case for interleaving 8 bits at a time.